# Is there a maven/NuGet equivalent for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Maven & NuGet are really useful for Java & C# projects. Is there something equivalent for JavaScript libraries?

Comment: Do you mean like `npm` but with an interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript has Node Package Manager ([NPM](https://www.npmjs.com))

Interface for NPM ([npm-gui](https://github.com/q-nick/npm-gui))